# leaflet.js: too slow with custom svg markers (and a lot of points)

Tags: d3.js, svg, canvas, leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to use some user defined svg icons for markers on leaflet but I think the whole task gets too heavy for my browser.

Until now I was using `L.circleMarker` but I now have to use markers like asterisks, arrows, stars etc instead so I decided to do them as svg path and then plug them in instead of my circleMarkers. To make things more complicated I have more than 300K points. With the circleMarkers I was able to make a workable chart, not lightning fast but quite acceptable especially when a fairly deep zoom was used to be able to distinguish individual points (otherwise everything was like a big blob and useless to study).

With the svg markers however the chart becomes so computationally heavy that the browser just hangs. I have played around with 100, 1000 and 10000 points and even with 1000 points the difference becomes apparent. Is there any solution to this please, has anyone used svg markers with lots of data points? I think canvas is properly employed in my code, especially for the `circleMarkers` but I might be mistaken. Any help highly appreciated. Code in the snippet, comment/uncomment the few lines towards the bottom:

```
return L.circleMarker(p, style(feature));
```

or

```
console.log("Starting markers.")
return L.marker(p, {
    renderer: myRenderer,
    icon: makeIcon('6-pointed-star', style(feature).color),
    });
```

to switch from the `circleMarkers` to `svg` markers.
Many thanks!

PS. With svg markers the code breaks with the highlight event but I have quite understood whats wrong..it works fine with `circleMarkers`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Chart</title>
    <style>
        #tooltip {
          position:absolute;
          background-color: #2B292E;
          color: white;
          font-family: sans-serif;
          font-size: 15px;
          pointer-events: none; /*dont trigger events on the tooltip*/
          padding: 15px 20px 10px 20px;
          text-align: center;
          opacity: 0;
          border-radius: 4px;
        }

  html, body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
  }
  #map {
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
  }
    </style>

<!-- Reference style.css -->
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">-->

<!-- Reference minified version of D3 -->
    <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



<div id="map"></div>


<script>
    var data = [];
    var NumOfPoints = 100
    for (let i = 0; i < NumOfPoints; i++) {
        data.push({
            num: i,
            x: Math.random(),
            y: Math.random(),
            year: Math.floor(100*Math.random())
        })
    }
    
    renderChart(data);


    function make_dots(data) {
        var arr = [];
        var nest = d3.nest()
            .key(function (d) {
                return Math.floor(d.year / 10);;
            })
            .entries(data);

        for (var k = 0; k < nest.length; ++k) {
            arr[k] = helper(nest[k].values);
        }
        return arr;
    }

    function helper(data) {
        dots = {
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            features: []
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            x = data[i].x;
            y = data[i].y;
            var g = {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [x, y]
            };

            //create feature properties
            var p = {
                "id": i,
                "popup": "Dot_" + i,
                "year": parseInt(data[i].year),
                "size": 30 // Fixed size
            };

            //create features with proper geojson structure
            dots.features.push({
                "geometry": g,
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": p
            });
        }
        return dots;
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //styling and displaying the data as circle markers//
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //create color ramp
    function getColor(y) {
        return y > 90 ? '#6068F0' :
            y > 80 ? '#6B64DC' :
            y > 70 ? '#7660C9' :
            y > 60 ? '#815CB6' :
            y > 50 ? '#8C58A3' :
            y > 40 ? '#985490' :
            y > 30 ? '#A3507C' :
            y > 20 ? '#AE4C69' :
            y > 10 ? '#B94856' :
            y > 0 ? '#C44443' :
            '#D04030';
    }

    //calculate radius so that resulting circles will be proportional by area
    function getRadius(y) {
        r = Math.sqrt(y / Math.PI)
        return r;
    }

    // This is very important! Use a canvas otherwise the chart is too heavy for the browser when
    // the number of points is too high, as in this case where we have around 300K points to plot
    var myRenderer = L.canvas({
        padding: 0.5
    });

    //create style, with fillColor picked from color ramp
    function style(feature) {
        return {
            radius: getRadius(feature.properties.size),
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.year),
            color: "#000",
            weight: 0,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.9,
            renderer: myRenderer
        };
    }

    //create highlight style, with darker color and larger radius
    function highlightStyle(feature) {
        return {
            radius: getRadius(feature.properties.size) + 1.5,
            fillColor: "#FFCE00",
            color: "#FFCE00",
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.9
        };
    }

    //attach styles and popups to the marker layer
    function highlightDot(e) {
        var layer = e.target;
        dotStyleHighlight = highlightStyle(layer.feature);
        layer.setStyle(dotStyleHighlight);
        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
            layer.bringToFront();
        }
    }

    function resetDotHighlight(e) {
        var layer = e.target;
        dotStyleDefault = style(layer.feature);
        layer.setStyle(dotStyleDefault);
    }

    function onEachDot(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightDot,
            mouseout: resetDotHighlight
        });
        var popup = '<table style="width:110px"><tbody><tr><td><div><b>Marker:</b></div></td><td><div>' + feature.properties.popup +
            '</div></td></tr><tr class><td><div><b>Group:</b></div></td><td><div>' + feature.properties.year +
            '</div></td></tr><tr><td><div><b>X:</b></div></td><td><div>' + feature.geometry.coordinates[0] +
            '</div></td></tr><tr><td><div><b>Y:</b></div></td><td><div>' + feature.geometry.coordinates[1] +
            '</div></td></tr></tbody></table>'

        layer.bindPopup(popup);
    }
    
    function makeIcon(name, color) {

    if (name == "diamond") {
        // here's the SVG for the marker
        var icon = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' width='20' height='20'> " +
            "<path stroke=" + "'" + color + "'" + " stroke-width='3' fill='none' " +
            " d='M10,1 5,10 10,19, 15,10Z'/></svg>";
    }


    // Based on http://www.smiffysplace.com/stars.html
    if (name == "6-pointed-star") {
        // here's the SVG for the marker
        var icon = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' width='28' height='28'> " +
            "<path stroke=" + "'" + color + "'" + " stroke-width='3' fill='none' " +
            " d='m13 13m0 5l5 3.6599999999999966l-0.6700000000000017 -6.159999999999997l5.670000000000002 -2.5l-5.670000000000002 -2.5l0.6700000000000017 -6.159999999999997l-5 3.6599999999999966l-5 -3.6599999999999966l0.6700000000000017 6.159999999999997l-5.670000000000002 2.5l5.670000000000002 2.5l-0.6700000000000017 6.159999999999997z'/></svg>";

    }


    // here's the trick, base64 encode the URL
    var svgURL = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(icon);

    // create icon
    var svgIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: svgURL,
        iconSize: [20, 20],
        shadowSize: [12, 10],
        iconAnchor: [5, 5],
        popupAnchor: [5, -5]
    });

    return svgIcon
}
    

    function renderChart(data) {
        var myDots = make_dots(data);

        var minZoom = 0,
            maxZoom = 15;

        var map = L.map('map', {
            minZoom: minZoom,
            maxZoom: maxZoom
        }).setView([0.5, 0.5], 10);

        L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
            continuousWorld: false,
            minZoom: 0,
            noWrap: true
        }).addTo(map);

        var myRenderer = L.canvas({
            padding: 0.5
        });

        // Define an array to keep layerGroups
        var dotlayer = [];

        //create marker layer and display it on the map
        for (var i = 0; i < myDots.length; i += 1) {
            dotlayer[i] = L.geoJson(myDots[i], {
                pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                    var p = latlng;
//                    return L.circleMarker(p, style(feature));
                    console.log("Starting markers.")
                    return L.marker(p, {
                        renderer: myRenderer,
                        icon: makeIcon('6-pointed-star', style(feature).color),
                    });
                },
                onEachFeature: onEachDot
            }).addTo(map);
        }


        var cl = L.control.layers(null, {}).addTo(map);
        for (j = 0; j < dotlayer.length; j += 1) {
            var name = "Group " + j + "0-" + j + "9";
            cl.addOverlay(dotlayer[j], name);
        }

    }


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use fewer points or move to canvas as a rendering technology.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your svg 6-point markers are not rendered by the Canvas. Have a look with the DevTools and you see they are `img` tags with a base-64 encoded svg as source. If you have a large number of markers this will slow down the HTML renderer.

The CircleMarkers are rendered on the canvas.

By creating a new `L.Path` subclass you can draw any marker you want on the canvas and let leaflet do what it does best. Make these leaflet modifications before any other JS code otherwise it will complain that it is not a constructor.

```
L.Canvas.include({
    _updateMarker6Point: function (layer) {
        if (!this._drawing || layer._empty()) { return; }

        var p = layer._point,
            ctx = this._ctx,
            r = Math.max(Math.round(layer._radius), 1);

        this._drawnLayers[layer._leaflet_id] = layer;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(p.x + r     , p.y );
        ctx.lineTo(p.x + 0.43*r, p.y + 0.25 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x + 0.50*r, p.y + 0.87 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x         , p.y + 0.50 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x - 0.50*r, p.y + 0.87 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x - 0.43*r, p.y + 0.25 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x -      r, p.y );
        ctx.lineTo(p.x - 0.43*r, p.y - 0.25 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x - 0.50*r, p.y - 0.87 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x         , p.y - 0.50 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x + 0.50*r, p.y - 0.87 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x + 0.43*r, p.y - 0.25 * r);
        ctx.closePath();
        this._fillStroke(ctx, layer);
    }
});

var Marker6Point = L.CircleMarker.extend({
    _updatePath: function () {
        this._renderer._updateMarker6Point(this);
    }
});
```

You use it the same as for the circleMarker

```
return new Marker6Point(p, style(feature));
```

In the code there are 2 `L.canvas` instances and there are 2 variables `myRenderer`. I have kept the global variable but assign it only when there is an L.map() constructed in the `renderChart()` function.

For the demo I have used a larger area with markers and used 10000 markers. My browser has no problems with that. I have increased the `size` in the properties to 500 so we get a marker with radius 13 pixels, so you can see the star clearly.

I have used the latest leaflet version 1.3.3.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Chart</title>
<style>
#tooltip {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #2B292E;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    pointer-events: none; /*dont trigger events on the tooltip*/
    padding: 15px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#map {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}
</style>

<!-- Reference style.css -->
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">-->

<!-- Reference minified version of D3 -->
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
L.Canvas.include({
    _updateMarker6Point: function (layer) {
        if (!this._drawing || layer._empty()) { return; }

        var p = layer._point,
            ctx = this._ctx,
            r = Math.max(Math.round(layer._radius), 1);

        this._drawnLayers[layer._leaflet_id] = layer;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(p.x + r     , p.y );
        ctx.lineTo(p.x + 0.43*r, p.y + 0.25 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x + 0.50*r, p.y + 0.87 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x         , p.y + 0.50 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x - 0.50*r, p.y + 0.87 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x - 0.43*r, p.y + 0.25 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x -      r, p.y );
        ctx.lineTo(p.x - 0.43*r, p.y - 0.25 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x - 0.50*r, p.y - 0.87 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x         , p.y - 0.50 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x + 0.50*r, p.y - 0.87 * r);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x + 0.43*r, p.y - 0.25 * r);
        ctx.closePath();
        this._fillStroke(ctx, layer);
    }
});

var Marker6Point = L.CircleMarker.extend({
    _updatePath: function () {
        this._renderer._updateMarker6Point(this);
    }
});

var data = [];
var NumOfPoints = 10000;
for (let i = 0; i < NumOfPoints; i++) {
    data.push({
        num: i,
        x: Math.random()*60,
        y: Math.random()*60,
        year: Math.floor(100*Math.random())
    })
}

renderChart(data);

function make_dots(data) {
    var arr = [];
    var nest = d3.nest()
        .key(function (d) {
            return Math.floor(d.year / 10);
        })
        .entries(data);

    for (var k = 0; k < nest.length; ++k) {
        arr[k] = helper(nest[k].values);
    }
    return arr;
}

function helper(data) {
    dots = {
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: []
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        x = data[i].x;
        y = data[i].y;
        var g = {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [x, y]
        };

        //create feature properties
        var p = {
            "id": i,
            "popup": "Dot_" + i,
            "year": parseInt(data[i].year),
            "size": 500 // Fixed size circle radius=~13
        };

        //create features with proper geojson structure
        dots.features.push({
            "geometry": g,
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": p
        });
    }
    return dots;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//styling and displaying the data as circle markers//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//create color ramp
function getColor(y) {
    return y > 90 ? '#6068F0' :
        y > 80 ? '#6B64DC' :
        y > 70 ? '#7660C9' :
        y > 60 ? '#815CB6' :
        y > 50 ? '#8C58A3' :
        y > 40 ? '#985490' :
        y > 30 ? '#A3507C' :
        y > 20 ? '#AE4C69' :
        y > 10 ? '#B94856' :
        y > 0 ? '#C44443' :
        '#D04030';
}

//calculate radius so that resulting circles will be proportional by area
function getRadius(y) {
    r = Math.sqrt(y / Math.PI)
    return r;
}

// This is very important! Use a canvas otherwise the chart is too heavy for the browser when
// the number of points is too high, as in this case where we have around 300K points to plot
var myRenderer;
//  = L.canvas({
//     padding: 0.5
// });

//create style, with fillColor picked from color ramp
function style(feature) {
    return {
        radius: getRadius(feature.properties.size),
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.year),
        color: "#000",
        weight: 0,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.9,
        renderer: myRenderer
    };
}

//create highlight style, with darker color and larger radius
function highlightStyle(feature) {
    return {
        radius: getRadius(feature.properties.size) + 1.5,
        fillColor: "#FFCE00",
        color: "#FFCE00",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.9
    };
}

//attach styles and popups to the marker layer
function highlightDot(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    dotStyleHighlight = highlightStyle(layer.feature);
    layer.setStyle(dotStyleHighlight);
    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }
}

function resetDotHighlight(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    dotStyleDefault = style(layer.feature);
    layer.setStyle(dotStyleDefault);
}

function onEachDot(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightDot,
        mouseout: resetDotHighlight
    });
    var popup = '<table style="width:110px"><tbody><tr><td><div><b>Marker:</b></div></td><td><div>' + feature.properties.popup +
        '</div></td></tr><tr class><td><div><b>Group:</b></div></td><td><div>' + feature.properties.year +
        '</div></td></tr><tr><td><div><b>X:</b></div></td><td><div>' + feature.geometry.coordinates[0] +
        '</div></td></tr><tr><td><div><b>Y:</b></div></td><td><div>' + feature.geometry.coordinates[1] +
        '</div></td></tr></tbody></table>'

    layer.bindPopup(popup);
}

function makeIcon(name, color) {

    if (name == "diamond") {
        // here's the SVG for the marker
        var icon = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' width='20' height='20'> " +
            "<path stroke=" + "'" + color + "'" + " stroke-width='3' fill='none' " +
            " d='M10,1 5,10 10,19, 15,10Z'/></svg>";
    }

    // Based on http://www.smiffysplace.com/stars.html
    if (name == "6-pointed-star") {
        // here's the SVG for the marker
        var icon = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' width='28' height='28'> " +
            "<path stroke=" + "'" + color + "'" + " stroke-width='3' fill='none' " +
            " d='m13 13m0 5l5 3.66l-0.67 -6.16l5.67 -2.5l-5.67 -2.5l0.67 -6.16l-5 3.66l-5 -3.66l0.67 6.16l-5.67 2.5l5.67 2.5l-0.67 6.16z'/></svg>";
    }

    // here's the trick, base64 encode the URL
    var svgURL = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(icon);

    // create icon
    var svgIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: svgURL,
        iconSize: [20, 20],
        shadowSize: [12, 10],
        iconAnchor: [5, 5],
        popupAnchor: [5, -5]
    });

    return svgIcon
}

function renderChart(data) {
    var myDots = make_dots(data);

    var minZoom = 0,
        maxZoom = 15;

    var map = L.map('map', {
        minZoom: minZoom,
        maxZoom: maxZoom
    }).setView([0.5, 0.5], 5);

    L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        continuousWorld: false,
        minZoom: 0,
        noWrap: true
    }).addTo(map);

    myRenderer = L.canvas({ padding: 0.5 });

    // Define an array to keep layerGroups
    var dotlayer = [];

    //create marker layer and display it on the map
    for (var i = 0; i < myDots.length; i += 1) {
        dotlayer[i] = L.geoJson(myDots[i], {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                var p = latlng;
                // return L.circleMarker(p, style(feature));

                // console.log("Starting markers.")
                // return L.marker(p, {
                //     renderer: myRenderer,
                //     icon: makeIcon('6-pointed-star', style(feature).color),
                // });

                return new Marker6Point(p, style(feature));
            },
            onEachFeature: onEachDot
        }).addTo(map);
    }
    var cl = L.control.layers(null, {}).addTo(map);
    for (j = 0; j < dotlayer.length; j += 1) {
        var name = "Group " + j + "0-" + j + "9";
        cl.addOverlay(dotlayer[j], name);
    }
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

If this is not fast enough you can always set up your own tile server and bake the markers into the tiles at the different zoom levels (in transparent PNG files). And use this as a separate tile layer on top of the terrain tiles. You don't have easy popups but the rendering of 300K markers is pretty fast. You can make a tile overlay for each layer/group you want to show. All serviced from the same tile server.

Comment: rioV8, thats absolutely amazing. I works fine, although somewhat slower than leaflet's circleMarkers (for 300K points). I might be able to get away with it. For the other other approach, do you have a pointer please (not asking you to write it, just if you have seen it somewhere so I will be able see how it is done). Also, how did you do the svg path for the 6point star, I will need to do some other shapes please. I can understand typical svg paths but that is new to me. The layer._radius, where this come from please? I need to make the markers larger and I guess this is what I have to set.

Comment: @Aenaon: it uses the same properties as the CircleMarker. You set the `radius` in the `style` and `highlight` methods, this is stored in `layer._radius` by the circleMarker constructor. Because we have more `ctx` calls and need to fill a more complex shape compared to the circle it takes a bit more time. Search for `web map tile service wmts` or `WMS`. Look at leaflet examples for tile overlay. The relative coords in the svg path did not make sence (goto-relative 13,13 | goto-relative 0,5 [where is this point??]) to me immediately so I recalculated them all relative to the midpoint.

Comment: Excellent answer -- perhaps it's my versions of leaflet v1.5.1, but I had to replace `this._drawnLayers[layer._leaflet_id] = layer;` to `this._layers[layer._leaflet_id] = layer;`. `_drawnLayers` was `undefined`

Comment: @walking_the_cow: I have no idea which version I used for the answer, and maybe they have changed this internal API. '_' means non-public stuff

Comment: @walking_the_cow: I am using v1.3.1 and works like a charm. Havent tried to update and I dont plan to since I dont see the reason to do so. Big thanks to rioV8 once again!

Comment: @rioV8: In case you see this, with regards to your comments in the last paragraph of your answer back in Aug2018 about prebaking the markers into tiles as transparent PNGs do you have any pointers that I could read and see how this is done?

Comment: @Aenaon. You need to implement a web server like you use for the terrain tiles. Serve an image based on the web request containing x,y,zoom. This is definitely more work than an SO answer.

Comment: @rioV8, yes sure, I dont expect you to write code for this here (or elsewhere). Just in case you have come across some material (blogs, books, anything really) discussing this approach to see how it is done. I think what I am missing is how to do those transparent tiles with the markers already pre-rendered on them as pngs. I guess there must me a lot more I dont know. Many thanks again

Comment: @Aenaon: the web server uses some projection, could be world wide WGS84 or some local like UK-grid. Then project your locations to the used projection coordinates and draw the marker on the tiles, be aware of the marker overlapping multiple tiles (up to 4) if your marker is smaller than a tile. Do this for every zoom level supported by the tile server. You can do on the fly or pre-bake the tiles for static data sets. Maybe do a daily pre-bake.