# Markers extended from CircleMarker - How to change the click area?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

With Leaflet, I'm trying to render a lot of points (+ 10000) as a GeoJSON feature to improve performance. In order to achieve better results, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852641/11064013) instructing on how to extend Leaflet's `circleMarker` to change it's shape like so:

```
L.Canvas.include({
    _updateMarkerPin: function(layer) {
        if (!this._drawing || layer._empty()) {
            return
        }

        var p = layer._point,
            ctx = this._ctx,
            r = layer._radius

        this._drawnLayers[layer._leaflet_id] = layer

        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y)
        ctx.lineTo(p.x - 0.58 * r, p.y - r)
        ctx.arc(p.x, p.y - 2 * r, r, -Math.PI * 1.161, Math.PI * 0.161)
        ctx.closePath()
        this._fillStroke(ctx, layer)
    },
})

const MarkerPin = L.CircleMarker.extend({
    _updatePath: function() {
        this._renderer._updateMarkerPin(this)
    },
})
```

This is my MarkerPin Shape:

[image: MarkerPin]

`MarkerPin` is then used in `L.GeoJSON`'s `pointToLayer` option as follows:

```
const myPointToLayer = (feature, latlng) => {
    var markerParams = {
        radius: 16,
        stroke: true,
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 0.4,
        fillOpacity: 0.9,
    }
    return new MarkerPin(latlng, markerParams)
}

const myOnEachFeature = (feature, layer) => {
    layer.bindPopup('Clicked me!')
}

L.geoJSON(data, {
    pointToLayer:myPointToLayer,
    onEachFeature: myOnEachFeature,
}).addTo(map);
```

So far so good. All the data gets rendered properly.
My problem is: the click area isn't updated according to my new shape, it stays like the `circleMarker`'s one (because that's what I've extended to create my pin) illustrated by the red circle:

[image: MarkerPin click area]

Other Leaflet elements, like polygons, have their click area match their shape. That being said, is it possible to change the click area of my `MarkerPin` to match my shape (even if I'm extending `circleMarker`)?

Even if it's not possible to change the shape of the click area, I'd be satisfied to being able to move it up a bit like the image below:

[image: MarkerPin recentered click area]

Or even, is there a better approach to render several markers in GeoJSON with a custom icon and handle their popups with Leaflet?

**Edit**

For completeness, this is what I'm using (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56072877/11064013), which uses the whole pin area:

```
const MarkerPin = L.CircleMarker.extend({
    _updatePath: function() {
        this._renderer._updateMarkerPin(this)
    },
    _containsPoint: function(p) {
        let r = this._radius

        let insideCircle =
            p.add([0, r * 2]).distanceTo(this._point) <= r + this._clickTolerance()

        let a = this._point,
            b = a.subtract([0.58 * r, r]),
            c = a.subtract([-0.58 * r, r])

        let insideTriangle = true

        let ap_x = p.x - a.x
        let ap_y = p.y - a.y

        let p_ab = (b.x - a.x) * ap_y - (b.y - a.y) * ap_x > 0
        let p_ac = (c.x - a.x) * ap_y - (c.y - a.y) * ap_x > 0
        let p_bc = (c.x - b.x) * (p.y - b.y) - (c.y - b.y) * (p.x - b.x) > 0

        if (p_ac === p_ab) {
            insideTriangle = false
        }
        if (p_bc !== p_ab) {
            insideTriangle = false
        }
        return insideTriangle || insideCircle
    },
})
```

Comment: Any reason why not using clustering? Typically with Leaflet.markercluster plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click detection in vector layers rendered through a `L.Canvas` depends on the `_containsPoint` private method of each vector layers. See the [implementation on `CircleMarker`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/c4487255e71505c98131f040c70a913b2de78e1c/src/layer/vector/CircleMarker.js#L94) or [on `Polyline`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/c4487255e71505c98131f040c70a913b2de78e1c/src/layer/vector/Polyline.js#L300).

Each time the [user clicks on a `L.Canvas` renderer, the renderer loops through all the layers in it](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/c4487255e71505c98131f040c70a913b2de78e1c/src/layer/vector/Canvas.js#L343), and asks them "the user has done something in pixel `p` - is this yours"? The call to `_containsPoint` has to answer that.

So you'll have to play around with implementing `_containsPoint` for your `MarkerPin` class, maybe something like e.g.

```
const MarkerPin = L.CircleMarker.extend({
    _updatePath: function() {
        this._renderer._updateMarkerPin(this)
    },
    _containsPoint: function(p) {
        return L.CircleMarker.prototype._containsPoint.call(this, p.subtract([0, 10]));
    }
})
```

That should shift the click area up or down. If you want a better shape, you'll have to provide a proper implementation of a function that returns whether a point in inside the shape or not.