# Leaflet - draw on separate canvas overlay

Tags: javascript, leaflet

The example of markerPin is taken from
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56067809) which is intended to be drawn on a separate canvas overlay.

By default it is drawn on the canvas created in the leaflet library.
I want to create this given example on a new canvas where the drawing is updated accordingly on zoom or on pan.
I need help with how to approach this problem.

I tried the approach of extending layer from the example [here](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html#onadd-and-onremove), but it does not work, and I am not sure of how to approach it.

Fiddle to this,
https://jsfiddle.net/vyz07113/qcy7oevs/41/

My canvas overlay approach,

```
var customlayer = L.Layer.extend({
initialize: function (options) {
    this._map = mymap;
    this._canvas = null;
    this._frame = null;
    this._delegate = null;
    L.setOptions(this, options);
    this.onAdd();
},
onAdd: function(){
    this._canvas = L.DomUtil.create('canvas', 'leaflet-layer custom');
    var size = this._map.getSize();
    this._canvas.width = size.x;
    this._canvas.height = size.y;
    this._map._panes.overlayPane.appendChild(this._canvas);
}});new customlayer();
```

I need help with,

1. Redraw when any event is triggered

2. Prevent canvas to pan with the map and update the drawing accordingly

Comment: Im not quite sure what you want to achive, but you could draw the layer using an extra pane and extra renderer https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#canvas

Comment: @Ludi Renderer adds the shape which i took from the example marked at the beginning.
It draws on the canvas which is created in the leaflet library. I want to create a new layer i,e canvas in the overlay pane and draw the example on it, not the default one from the leaflet.

Comment: You can do that, by creating a seperate renderer just for your markers.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a seperate Leafet Canvas Renderer just for these markers:

```
mymap.createPane("customPane");
var canvasRenderer = L.canvas({pane:"customPane"});
var marker = new L.marker([0,0],{renderer:canvasRenderer});
```

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#canvas

**EDIT:** The working fiddle [here (updated)](https://jsfiddle.net/vyz07113/qcy7oevs/45/)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am editing the answer to attach the link of the fix.